# Jquery plugin input field to accept more than one IP address

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to use a Jquery plugin for handling IPV4 addresses. Plugin is available at https://github.com/felipevolpatto/jquery-input-ip-address-control

The issue is I can use only one text field for IPV4 address. If I use one more, I could see only normal text field with out any separators. How can I use it for more than one text field for IPV4 address?

**Code:**

```
<form role="form">

                    <div class="form-group">
                            <label>Starting Address</label></br>                        
                            <input type="text" name="ip1" id="ipv4">

                        </div>  
                        <div class="form-group">                                
                            <label>Ending Address</label></br>                        
                            <input type="text" name="ip2" id="ipv4">
                        </div>    


 </form>      
<script src="js/jquery.input-ip-address-control-1.0.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $(function(){
        $('#ipv4').ipAddress();
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot use same id in this case. Change `id="ipv4"` to `class="ipv4"` and try

```
$(function(){
        $('.ipv4').ipAddress();
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

The `id` is a global unique identifier. It's supposed to be used for only a single element on a page. If the same `id` is repeated, generally only the first is selected, but that can vary, and you're NOT supposed to do that. If you want to apply `ipv4` to another element, you should make it a class.

`class="ipv4"`

and change the JQuery to reflect that:

```
$(function(){
    $('.ipv4').ipAddress();
});
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/id